# Temporary value error on SaveChanges in EF Core

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

When adding values to a table in EF Core I get the following error

> The property ... has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Unchanged'. Either set a permanent value explicitly, or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

#### What is the code doing?

Imagine you have a table of data with multiple columns and you are attempting to store that table of data (think CSV, xslx etc) in a normalised form in a database. Some of the facets (columns) have their values already stored in the database, some need to be added, and some need to be updated.

A loose idea of the format of the source is...

`Name, Facet1, Facet2, Facet2_1, Facet2_2, Numeric1, Numeric2`

Where we will end up in the database with

```
Id, Name, Facet1_Id, Facet2_Id, Numeric1, Numeric2
Id, Facet1
Id, Facet2, Facet2_1_Id, Facet2_2_Id
Id, Facet2_1
Id, Facet2_2
```

The facet tables can be extended and the facet2 table can also be updated as the additional fields change from time to time. Facet2 table is system versioned.

#### Workflow

- Load the file data
- begin transaction
- Fetch/extend facet1 data
- Fetch/extend/update facet2 data
- Map facets/ids (doesn't matter which way) to main data
- Save changes.
- end transaction

It is on the DbContext.SaveChanges() that the error occurs. If I perform a dirty read on the database (query with (nolock)) I see that every row of data I have processed is stored, which is not what I'd expect. I would expect at least one value to be missing to generate the issue. This seems like it succeeded but had some kind of internal EF issue.

The main data entity is setup with Id field as `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption).Identity` as are the Id fields for the other tables.

I have also tried with or without `builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` but still get the issue.

I have a different project in the solution that performs a similar task except the foreign keys do not go as many levels deep i.e. here I have

```
  Main entity
   |         |
Facet1     Facet2
           |     |
       Facet2_1 Facet2_2
```

whereas the other project extends only one level in its processing/linking.

- EF Core 7.0.0
- SQL Server 2019
- .NET 6.0

Comment: This is hard to analyze w/o a [mre]. You should investigate where entities are set `Unchanged`. It makes sense that you don't see them as saved records.

Comment: That's the point though - they do get saved within the confines of the transaction, hence they are readable from SQL Management Studio using (nolock). My guess is that EF stores the data then internally marks the entities and it is in this process the issue occurs. As I get an error the transaction is not completed and rolled back. To be honest it's pretty hard to reproduce full system errors involving enterprise databases hence the overview above.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed by updating EF Core from 7.0.0 to 7.0.5

Comment: I was skeptical of this as being the correct answer. However, I had a project that was hitting the same exception (The property ... has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Unchanged'.). My project was referencing EFCore 7.0.1, and when I updated to 7.0.5, the error could no longer be reproduced. In lieu of another solution, this one should be marked as the answer.